# semantic ui react reveal interact with hidden form

Tags: reactjs, hidden, visible, semantic-ui-react

Using Semantic ui React's Reveal with two different Cards. The visible one and then the hidden one. But the hidden one has a form and button that I need to interact with. Is there an easy way to make the form accessible? Or is the really only way to do so find the item with JS and then remove the attribute to interact with? Please someone give me some advice. Here is my current code for the Reveal.And yes I know code is sloppy right now. It's temporary.

```
<Reveal animated='fade' instant key={i}>
  <Reveal.Content visible>
    <Card
      centered={true}
      key={i}
      raised={true}
      style={{'backgroundColor':'blue', color:'white'}}
    >
      <Card.Header textAlign='center' as='h1'>
        {Object.keys(each).toString()}
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Header textAlign='center' as='h3'>
        No peeking on other players wagers!
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Header as='h1'></Card.Header>
      <Card.Header as='h1'></Card.Header>
      <Card.Header as='h2'></Card.Header>
    </Card>
  </Reveal.Content>

  <Reveal.Content hidden>
    <Card
      centered={true}
      key={i}
      raised={true}
    >
      <Card.Header textAlign='center' as='h1'>
        {Object.keys(each).toString()}
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Header textAlign='center' as='h3'>
        Please make your wager!
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Content>
        <Form
          as='form'
        >
          <Form.Field>
            <Label>Place your Wager</Label>
            <Input icon='money' iconPosition='right' focus placeholder='Wager' />
          </Form.Field>
          <Button 
            type='submit'
            size='large'
            color='blue'
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  </Reveal.Content>
</Reveal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically your top content in your Reveal is covering the form below. Only the opacity is changing. It's still in the DOM with a higher z-index.

There are a number of ways you could solve this.

1) When the animation ends, set a `display: none` on the top "visible" Reveal. That means you'd have to listen to the animation end. And when the mouse leaves you would need to add `display: block` back so you can see the animation. Probably more work than you need.

2) Change the z-index to a lower value when the animation ends. Same issue as above.

3) Set `pointer-events: none` on the top "visible" reveal. This effectively makes the user's click events pass through the transparent Reveal and hit the form below instead. This is important to know, in case you intend to use the Reveal at some point to actually block the form. `<Reveal.Content visible style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}>`